# How to fetch/edit an embedded document from a listfield in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

I have the following structure of data

```
class Change(EmbeddedDocument):
    type = IntField()
    by_user = ReferenceField(User)
    date_time = DateTimeField()

class Doc(Document):
    title = StringField()
    ...
    change_history = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField("Change"))
```

How do I fetch all the changes performed by a user on a Doc?
How do I edit a change performed by a user on a Doc?

Comment: Your questions are vague. For Q1: do you need to fetch all changes by specified user on one document (the use elemMatch) or across whole "Doc" collection (then you cannot do it on mongo level)? And for second one - how are you going to edit it? You want just do atomic update of document knowing the position of change in the list or how do you specify WHICH change to edit?

Comment: How do I fetch all the changes performed by a user on **a** Doc?
How do I edit **a** change performed by a user on **a** Doc?
I could edit it by datetime. it stores a timestamp.